# VSCode zshrc profile to load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code, zshrc

Everytime when I brought up terminal or run a python program, the VScode terminal will show the zshrc profile messed up like this:

```sh
$fg_bold[green]~/github/fundanalytics$reset_color$(git_prompt_info) ⌚ $fg_bold[red]16:44:35$reset_color
```

Only if I manually source `.zshrc` file once, it will load correctly like:

```
~/github/fundanalyticsgit:(master*) ⌚ 16:45:09
```

I have configured for:

```
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
```

Any thoughts?